# Backspace not working in Firefox in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input filed with an onkeypress event:

```
<input type="number" min = "0" id = "count" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' />
```

Basically this allows only numeric values to be entered into the field...and this works just fine... in Chrome, Firefox and IE.. which is enough for me. BUT the "backspace" key does not work in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome and IE. What I mean is if I want to type '15' and by accident I type '155'... when in Firefox I am not able to use "backspace" on that field. How can I make backspace work in Firefox?

Comment: pressing delete returns false and seems to halt the default response `<input type="number" min = "0" id = "count" onkeypress='console.log( event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)' />` as you see there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox - keypress bug. Can't use backspace with only letter input script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972258/firefox-keypress-bug-cant-use-backspace-with-only-letter-input-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a catch for the Backspace key:

```html
<input type="number" min = "0" id = "count" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.key === "Backspace"' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Below jQuery code snippets will allow only numbers in the textbox. However backspace and delete keys are also allowed.

```
   $("#testID").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey)
     e.preventDefault();
    else {
     var nKeyCode = e.keyCode;
     //Ignore Backspace and Tab keys
     if (nKeyCode == 8 || nKeyCode == 9)

      return;

     if (nKeyCode < 95) {
      if (nKeyCode < 48 || nKeyCode > 57)
       e.preventDefault();
     } else {
      if (nKeyCode < 96 || nKeyCode > 105)
       e.preventDefault();
     }
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#count');
input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  return (e.keyCode === 8 || (e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57));
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" id="count">
```

Comment: thank you but this allows me to enter whatever value I want into that input. I need it to allow only numeric characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for only allowing numbers instead:

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6dfrLz0p/12/

Comment: thank you @FirstLast but onchange allow users to enter non-numeric characters ;(